# SQL Server 2016 - row level security by AD group membership

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, row-level-security

I'm wondering if it is possible to use row level security based on a users AD group membership.

I would love to have something that could support users in different groups and some super users who have membership of all groups.

I suspect the answer is no, but any tips would be appreciated!

Comment: You should be able to use the is_member function in the predicate?

Comment: I did not know that existed, fantastic, thanks.

Comment: Post an answer if it all works.